# Let $g$ be an element of the group $G$. If $|g|>1$ and $|G| = 3*5*7$ is it true that $|g|=3$, $5$ or $7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $g$ be an element of the group $G$. If $|g|>1$ and $|G| = 3*5*7$ is it true that $|g|=3$, $5$ or $7$?

I think that answer is yes, because $|g| \ |\  |G|$. But on the other hand, I don't know why the order cannot be $3*5$, for example.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the integers mod $105$.

Comment: with addition ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: In the integers mod 105, there are elements with orders different from the orders above, right? Then the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments, but I think it's best to have answers to questions as answers.

The order of $g$ need not be $3$, $5$, or $7$. Indeed, it can be any product of these numbers that still divides $105$. You can check that all possible orders are realized in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{105}$ (those being $1,3,5,7,15,21,35,105$).